# How to show real timer clock in pubnub publish and subscribe method

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, pubnub, real-time-clock

```
        let timer =0;
    function showTime() {
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
    function letsGo(duration) {
        const pubnub = new PubNub({
            publishKey: 'pub-c-1bda0482-9e4d-4ae7-b95d-232b2d452050',
            subscribeKey: 'sub-c-e515c58a-69e0-11eb-b914-eedc703588a5',
            uuid: "myUniqueUUID"
        });
        var timer = duration;
            function  publishSampleMessage(){
                    var publishPayload ={
                        channel : "game-time",
                        message: {
                            data:setInterval(function () {
                            var  minutes, seconds;
                            if(timer>0)
                            {
                            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
                            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                            //console.log(minutes+":"+seconds);
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
                            timer--;                     
                            if (timer==0) {
                            
                                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Game is Over";
                                document.getElementById("game").innerHTML ="";                          
                            }
                            //timesender(timer);
                        }
                       
                    }, 1000),
                        mytime: --timer
                    }
                }
                pubnub.publish(publishPayload, function(status, response) {
                console.info("status publish function "+status);
                console.info("response publish function "+ response.timetoken);
                console.info(publishPayload);
                })
            }
            pubnub.addListener({
                status: function(statusEvent) {
                    if (statusEvent.category === "PNConnectedCategory") {
                        publishSampleMessage();
                    }
                },
                message: function(msg) {
                    console.log("sanu ki "+msg.message.data);
                   if(msg.message.mytime>0) {
                       console.log("tanu ki " + msg.message.mytime);
                       msg.message.mytime--;
                   }
                },
                presence: function(presenceEvent) {
                    // This is where you handle presence. Not important for now :)
                    console.log("presence "+presenceEvent.action);
                }
            })
            console.log("Subscribing...");
    
        pubnub.subscribe({
            channels: ['game-time'],
            withPresence: true
        });
        
    }
     function timesender(time){
                        console.log("time is this : "+time);
                    }
```

I am trying to publish a real-time countdown timer in PubNub through javascript but whenever I publish a message it appears something like a fixed number like 6 and it never appears like a countdown clock but in the console log it is appearing like a countdown clock. Please suggest me how to publish the countdown timer clock as an admin so that other users get listen to it. The basic idea is I have created an admin portal in PHP and JS where I am starting a countdown timer and unity mobile game users will be listening to that timer

Updated code after Stephen help:

```
     function letsGo(duration) {
            const channel = 'game-time';
            const pubnub = new PubNub({ publishKey : 'pub-c-1bda0482-9e4d-4ae7-b95d-232b2d452050', subscribeKey : 'sub-c-e515c58a-69e0-11eb-b914-eedc703588a5' });
            let countdown = 65; // seconds
            const countdownId = setInterval( countdownUpdate, 1000 );
            function countdownUpdate() {
                pubnub.publish({
                    channel : channel,
                    message : { 'countdown' : --countdown },
                });
                if (countdown <= 0) clearInterval(countdownId);
            }

        console.log("Subscribing...");

// Public user receiving updates on the countdown
            pubnub.subscribe({
                channels: [channel]
            });

            pubnub.addListener({ message: event => {
                    const timeLeft = event.message.countdown;
                    console.log("time left "+timeLeft)
                    const minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60) + '';
                    const seconds = Math.floor(timeLeft % 60) + '';
                    let dd = `${minutes.padStart(2,'0')}:${seconds.padStart(2,'0')}`;
                    document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML =
                        `${minutes.padStart(2,'0')}:${seconds.padStart(2,'0')}`;
                }});

}
```

I am getting a minor problem now. As basically I have created a letsGo function on a click button so whenever I am opening a timer page in another browser I am getting two clocks one is the continuation of the previous browser but there is another one that is getting started from beginning again

Comment: Hi @CraigConover, I am getting a minor problem now. As basically I have created a letsGo function on a click button so whenever I am opening a timer page in another browser I am getting two clocks one is the continuation of previous browser but there is another one which is getting start from beginning again

Comment: Man, I misread that title hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript Countdown Timer

> The bug in the code: **an int eventId value is published via PubNub.** This isn't the intended design.  The reason for this is explained following usage of `setInterval` function returning the eventId for the interval timer.

`let eventId = setInterval(...)` returns an integer that references the `setInterval` eventId on the browser's event loop stack.  The idea is that you can use the eventId to stop the interval later on with `clearInterval(eventId)`.

[image: JavaScript Countdown Timer]

Recommended Approach:

```js
(()=>{
'use strict';

const channel = 'game-time';
const pubnub = new PubNub({ publishKey : 'demo', subscribeKey : 'demo' });
let countdown = 65; // seconds
const countdownId = setInterval( countdownUpdate, 1000 );

// Secure Server --> this should be running on your node.js server.
function countdownUpdate() {
    pubnub.publish({
        channel : channel,
        message : { 'countdown' : --countdown },
    });
    if (countdown <= 0) clearInterval(countdownId);
}

// Public user receiving updates on the countdown
pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: [channel]
});

pubnub.addListener({ message: event => {
    const timeLeft = event.message.countdown;
    const minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60) + '';
    const seconds = Math.floor(timeLeft % 60) + '';
    document.querySelector('#timer').innerHTML =
        `${minutes.padStart(2,'0')}:${seconds.padStart(2,'0')}`;
}});

})();
```

```css
#timer {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.29.11.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">00:00</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Stephen, I am getting a minor problem now. As basically I have created a letsGo function on a click button so whenever I am opening a timer page in another browser I am getting two clocks one is the continuation of the previous browser but there is another one that is getting started from the beginning again

Comment: Are you opening second client in another tab or in another of the same browser? Is so, use different type of browser or use incognito mode.

Comment: @ArslaanMuhammadAli hi! yes. Your description makes sense.  Craig also mentions that the example code would start a second countdown. The second countdown will be mixed up with the first countdown.  A "letsGo" button will solve this.  Also, it is ideal to place the countdown JS logic on a server (nodejs) for security purposes.